# How do I take the value from one query and use it as the id for another?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to amend an existing table that is being populated with membership data. I've duplicate some of the code and amended it to successfully display a Members Team ID (Part 1 below). I've then duplicated it again and can successfully include the Team Expiry (Part 2) by **manually adding** the post meta id (in the example '105271').

I somehow need to replace the manual inserted post id in part 2 with the value that I'm getting from part 1.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Part 1

```
 elseif($table == 'memberships_team'){
    $query_joins .= " LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT MIN(CAST(meta_value AS UNSIGNED)) AS member_team, $wpdb->posts.post_author AS user_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID
        WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_team_id' 
        GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.post_author
    ) AS memberships_team ON $wpdb->users.ID = memberships_team.user_id";   
}
```

Part 2

```
 elseif($table == 'memberships_team_end'){
    $query_joins .= " LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT MIN(CAST(meta_value AS DATETIME)) AS member_team_end, $wpdb->posts.post_author AS user_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = '105271'
        WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_membership_end_date'
        GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.post_author
    ) AS memberships_team_end ON $wpdb->users.ID = memberships_team_end.user_id";
}
```

Comment: cant you simply declare a variable and populate in part 1 and then use it in part 2.

Comment: That's a bit beyond my knowledge levels unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I hope **part 1** is already executed to get controlled over **part 2** .

It means **memberships_team** has already been processed and the **member_team** column has been added to the query results.

then **Part 2** can be modified and it's required any intermediate variable as i commented.

```
elseif($table == 'memberships_team_end'){
    $query_joins .= " LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT MIN(CAST(meta_value AS DATETIME)) AS member_team_end, $wpdb->posts.post_author AS user_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = memberships_team.member_team
        WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_membership_end_date'
        GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.post_author
    ) AS memberships_team_end ON $wpdb->users.ID = memberships_team_end.user_id";
}
```

utilising **member_team** column obtained in **memberships_team** part 1.